# How to average the previous 5 cells that have values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this

[image]

I want to average only the previous 5 cells that have data in them. How can I do this?

As the list gets more data, like this:

[image]

I want to be able to target a cell (like A10) and go 5 back from that. Again, only if it has data in it.

So the formula for the image should be like this:  (23 + 60 + 53 + 42 + 40)/5  = 43.6

It's going backward and skipping the black space, yet still getting the 5 previous.

Answer (score 2):

The following formula assumes your values are on column A (adjust all `A:A` references if they're not):

```
=Average(Filter(Sort(A:A;If(A:A="";0;Row(A:A));false);Row(A:A)<6))
```

To understand the formula above, paste its parts separately (when you get a part without the `Filter` formula, you'll need to wrap it on an `ArrayFormula`. e.g.

```
=Filter(Sort(A:A;If(A:A="";0;Row(A:A));false);Row(A:A)<6)
=ArrayFormula( Sort(A:A; If(A:A="";0;Row(A:A)); false) )
=ArrayFormula( Row(A:A) )
```

Place these "auxiliary" formulas on empty columns you might have on the sheet (in the first cells, e.g. `D1`, `T1`).

For non-entire columns, like you suggested, you may also need to wrap the whole formula in an array formula, e.g.

```
=ArrayFormula( Average(Filter(Sort(K1:K10;If(K1:K10="";0;Row(K1:K10));false);Row(K1:K10)<6)) )
```

I initially thought that `Filter` formula would behave like the `ArrayFormula`, but it seems it does not "recursion" down to the inners of its parameters. Hance, the `ArrayFormula` is required for the `IF` to work properly. I do not know why it did work for `A:A` though.

Comment: Yeah, but I would like the 5 previous with values. So, say there were more values going down, I would only want to go 5 back from it, unless there was nothing in a cell, then it would need to go back 6. Does that make sense? So the 5 previous values, not necessarily the 5 previous cells.

Comment: Sorry, I understood your question totally wrong. Hope this is the correct/expected answer now.

Comment: there's an "extra" parenthesis on the formula. I fixed it. Please try

Comment: Take a look at my revised question. I don't understand how I can target a cell and go "back" or "up" from there.

Comment: It's sorting the entire row. I only want the previous 5 from the target cell.

Comment: I mean, it looks to me like I can't target a cell using the formula you are providing. I should be able to call K10 and have it automatically find the 5 previous cells going up that have values. Then average those.

Comment: Oh! That's the problem? I though you'd always want the real last 5. Anyway, just limit the range e.g. for `K10` change all `A:A` ranges to `K1:K10`

Comment: I don't want the sort, but I do want to filter out the ones that have no value. and I only want the previous 5 that have a value.

Comment: The `Sort` is just a technique to get the previous 5. It doesn't matter for the `Average`. I don't see a problem with it. What's the issue?

Comment: =Filter(Sort(K1:K10;If(K1:K10="";0;Row(K1:K10));false);Row(K1:K10)<6)   I get a "Range has no entry corresponding to this cell" error.

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully providing the correct answer. Have you seen it?